# Passing information from JavaScript to RB in Sinatra

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I'm reading some data from  elements, and want to send the information received to my .rb file, do I need to send it as JSON?

```
<li id="stream1">
            <label>Width: </label><input type="text" name="stream_width" size="5" class="width"><span>px</span>
            <label>Height: </label><input type="text" name="stream_height" size="5" class="height"><span>px</span>
            <label>Bitrate: </label><input type="text" name="stream_bitrate" size="5" class="bitrate"><span>kbps</span>
            </br>
        </li>
<li id="stream2">
            <label>Width: </label><input type="text" name="stream_width" size="5" class="width"><span>px</span>
            <label>Height: </label><input type="text" name="stream_height" size="5" class="height"><span>px</span>
            <label>Bitrate: </label><input type="text" name="stream_bitrate" size="5" class="bitrate"><span>kbps</span>
            </br>
        </li>

$('#checkInfo').click(function(){
    widths = $('.width');
    heights = $('.height');
    bitrates = $('.bitrate');

    $.each(widths, function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });

    $.each(heights, function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });

    $.each(bitrates, function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Here I want to store the info shown in console.log, and use it in my .rb file

Comment: What do you mean "use it my .rb file"? Are you showing it right away? Are you going to store it in a database? If you intend to store it you'll have send it to some URL with a PUT or POST request and that could use JSON, it could use query variables, or other options depending on your needs. If you're using Sinatra, your Sinatra app will have to handle that request, but this isn't really Sintra-specific question

Comment: Where is your `.rb` file?
I think you mean defining a `post` route for your form submission.

Comment: @SeanRedmond - What I am trying to do is to dynamically duplicate the content of li#stream1, reid it with stream2, and change the name of its nested elements to "stream_width2" "stream_height2" "stream_bitrate2" so that I can later get their content with params[:stream_width2].  The problem is, Sinatra can not read the content of DOM elements that where created prior to the page load.

Comment: Sinatra can't read the contents of any DOM element, nor can any webserver -- the DOM only exists in the browser as the browser's interpretation of the HTML sent by the server. If you want what you describe (which still isn't very clear) to happen on a click, you'll need to send the "stream2" data back to the server in an Ajax POST request which your Sinatra app will to have code to handle. Or maybe you could use HTLM5 local storage to save the "stream2" data in the browser.